# Entering a directory whose name matches a substring

Tags: bash, wildcard

I want to enter several directories in a for loop. I do not have the complete name of the directories, only a part of it.

I would like to do something like what you would write on the terminal, something like `cd *IncompleteDirName*`

This is a MVE of the loop: `IncompleteDirName`'s are obtained from the file `IncompleteDirNames`.

```
cont=1
sum=1
while read anotherFILE; do

        IncompleteDirName=$(sed "${cont}q;d" IncompleteDirNames)

        cd *"${IncompleteDirName}"*
        #  Do stuff
        cd ..
        cont=$((cont + sum))
done <anotherFILE
```

This is not working, I don't know if this has to do with wildcard not expanding or with variable not working properly.

It is throwing me this error message:

> *: No such file or directory

I suppose this means asterisk is not working as intended. It is not entering the directories, and there is a directory that matches every pattern. Anyway, no directory is being entered.

This is how `IncompleteDirNames` file looks like:

`Alicante
Almeria 
Andalucia 
Avila`

It is a column of names.
These are the directory names corresponding to the `IncompleteDirName`s above:

`aa4fas_Alicante_com`
`mun_Almeria`
`comunidadde_Andalucia`
`ciuAvila`

Comment: What does "not working" mean? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what's going on here, as this is an example that doesn't actually *run*. Substrings are in a file, those substrings are part of directory names, and you want to "do stuff" in each of the directories partially matched by a substring located in `FILE`? What if a substring matches multiple directories? What's inside the files `code` and `p-ca` ?

Comment: I am sure no multiple directories are matched. I have corrected the code.

Comment: You need to clarify what does not work.  One thing is for sure : if your incomplete name can match many directories, and you want to do something inside each of them, you need a loop for that.  You also need to prepare for the case where no directory matches, which in your tentative code will cause the "cd" command to fail but will not prevent the "Do stuff" part from being executed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still unclear. Can you show us a sample of what's in `FILE` as well as what's in `IncompleteDirNames`? Have you tried, right before the `cd` line, an `echo` of the same stuff you CD to, to make sure you're trying to change to something you intend to change to?

Comment: @ghoti Yes, I have, it `echo`es the incomplete directory name but starting with an asterisk.

Comment: Did you perhaps edit one of your input files on a Windows box, and have invisible carriage returns at the ends of lines? Without seeing your input data, we're still a little limited in terms of diagnosis.

Comment: You need to change the filename and the variable in while loop - 

`cont=1
sum=1
while read FILE; do

        IncompleteDirName=$(sed "${cont}q;d" FILE)

        cd *"${IncompleteDirName}"*
        #  Do stuff
        cd ..
        cont=$((cont + sum))
done <IncompleteDirNames`

Comment: You mentioned in comments elsewhere that you're getting different glob handling within the script than you get interactively. You haven't mentioned what shell you're using, and the script in your example includes no shebang that would tell us what interpreter you're using. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: That last thing was a typo from passing data here

Comment: @D1X - here's a hint ... If after 24 hours you don't have ANY answers that address your requirements, it's a good bet that your question needs some work. Clarifying all the elements in your example would be a start - you still haven't told us what's inside the file named `anotherFILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
cont=1
sum=1
while read FILE; do

        IncompleteDirName=$(sed "${cont}q;d" FILE)

        cd *"${IncompleteDirName}"*
        #  Do stuff
        cd ..
        cont=$((cont + sum))
done <IncompleteDirNames
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem, the while loops another file, and that has to remain like that.

Comment: Can you check if you have a file like "FILE" in the directory from which you are trying to execute while loop/script, because as you pasted the error details - 

`*: No such file or directory` Indicates that file is not available on which you are tyring to loop (In your code that filename is "FILE")

Comment: Yes, there is, I have just checked it.

Comment: Then mention the complete path of file `IncompleteDirNames` in your sed command and try.

Comment: Done. Anyway I have echoed `IncompleteDirName` and it is correctly storing the names. The problem has to do with asterisk not working as a wildcard, but as an asterisk itself

Comment: Good to hear that, Can you please paste your working code here because `cd *incompletedirname*` will work fine.

Comment: This has to do with scripts not using the same way asterisks. I have tried to reproduce this step by step and it works as intended. For some reason I can type `cd *$incompletedirname*` in the terminal and it works, but it does not work when used in a script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139045/discussion-between-vipin-kumar-and-d1x).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  cd /absolute/path/to/*$line*
  # do stuff
done < filename
```

This will enter each directory whose name partially matches a line in `filename`, and "does stuff".